# Express/Pug. Server side rendering vs client side rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am kind of confused when it comes down to what is client-side and what is server-side.
I am currently building a website, using Pug for my HTML pages, no HTML pages with `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` etc.

So am i rendering my pages Server side, since i don't have any files being loaded in the clients browser? Or is it client side, since the Client can click around and see things being updated?

I think what confuses me, is that normally when i build in Java i have HTML pages with scripts in them. But since i am building both front and backend in Javascript, it's kind of hard for me to understand who is rendering what.

I apologize if it's a huge noob question, but i would really like to understand it once and for all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, Java =/= JavaScript. Not the same. No relation whatsoever.

Comment: Pug is a templating engine. When you call `res.render(template, params)` in your route, pug loads the pug template, converts it to proper HTML and inserts the params / processes the code. That's server-side rendering, because the entire HTML is created on the server, then sent to the browser (the client). Client-side rendering would be a framework like React, where the entire UI is handled by the browser's JavaScript engine and scripts that are loaded from the server, then run in the browser.

Comment: Thank you :) That made sense.

Comment: Sorry, did you actually mean Java? So many people confuse JavaScript and Java I assume you did, too.

Comment: I know the difference between Java and Javascript :) Once again, thank you for a fast and useful answer.

Comment: When you do a `CTRL+U` (views page sources) on a page, what you see is server rendered. Other actions these manipulates the DOM are client-side stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, it's server-side rendering, because server compiles Pug to HTML then sends it to the client(already done HTML), unlike client-side frameworks(like angular, react, vue) where HTML page renders on client-side(browser).

Answer (score 0):

The scripts inside of `<script>` Tags are loaded by the client, and the JavaScript is also run by them.

What the server does is compile Pug to HTML so the client can display it.

If the client clicks something and it changes that is likely some front-end framework that is actively changing the DOM